# $.when().then() nested as a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a function, `query1()`, containing a $.when() promise which I would like to use as the argument for a parent $.when() promise. The value returned from query1() should be passed down the line, as in the variable `b`. The problem is that the parent $.when resolves before the child, but it needs to wait.

What's the best way to correct the order, so that the parent waits for the child to resolve?

```
$.when(query1(a))
.then( function(b) {

   console.log("step 3");

   return query2(b);

})
.then( function(c) {

   console.log("step 6")

});


function query1(a) {
   console.log("step 1");

   $.when(asynchronous_function())
   .then( function(data) {
      
      console.log("step 2");
      return data;

   });
}

function query2(b) {
   console.log("step 4");

   $.when(asynchronous_function())
   .then( function(data) {
      
      console.log("step 5");
      return data;

   });
}
```

Console will read:

```
Step 3
Step 6
Step 1
Step 2
Step 4
Step 5
```

I'm trying to avoid the "pyramid of death" thing here, to make my code both more readable and modular.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `query1` and `query2` function are missing `return` statements, they should return the promise

Comment: Btw why are you still using jQuery deferreds instead of real promises?

Comment: Where would I put the return statement?

Comment: Before the promise chain

Answer (score 0):

> The value returned from `query1()`...

That's what is missing: `query1()` has no `return` statement. The one in the `then` callback is a `return` statement for *that* callback function, not for `query1()`. Each `function` that needs to return something significant needs its *own* `return` statement.

So add it both in `query1` and `query2`.

```js
$.when(query1(1))
.then( function(b) {
   console.log("step 3", b);
   return query2(b);
})
.then( function(c) {
   console.log("step 6", c)
});


function query1(a) {
   console.log("step 1", a);
   return $.when(Promise.resolve(42*a))
   .then( function(data) {
      console.log("step 2", data);
      return data;
   });
}

function query2(b) {
   console.log("step 4", b);
   return $.when(Promise.resolve(b*144))
   .then( function(data) {
      console.log("step 5", data);
      return data;
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Having said that, there is no reason to call `$.when` when you are going to pass it a single promise object. That promise can be used directly to call `then` on it.

That would lead to this:

```js
query1(1)
.then( function(b) {
   console.log("step 3", b);
   return query2(b);
})
.then( function(c) {
   console.log("step 6", c)
});


function query1(a) {
   console.log("step 1", a);
   return Promise.resolve(42*a)
   .then( function(data) {
      console.log("step 2", data);
      return data;
   });
}

function query2(b) {
   console.log("step 4", b);
   return Promise.resolve(b*144)
   .then( function(data) {
      console.log("step 5", data);
      return data;
   });
}
```

Nowadays there is no good reason anymore to use jQuery deferred objects for working with promises. Since ECMA Script 2015 JavaScript has the native promises.

You can even use `async`/`await` syntax:

```js
(async () => {
    const b = await query1(1);
    console.log("step 3", b);
    const c = await query2(b);
    console.log("step 6", c)
})();

async function query1(a) {
    console.log("step 1", a);
    const data = await Promise.resolve(42*a);
    console.log("step 2", data);
    return data;
}

async function query2(b) {
    console.log("step 4", b);
    const data = await Promise.resolve(b*144);
    console.log("step 5", data);
    return data;
}
```